# 'vuex-persistedstate' won´t call actions and reload page

Tags: vue.js, vuex, persistent-storage

need some help.

Added vuex-persistedstate to proyect and it seems as it wont let me call my actions on store. When I hit a dispatch trying to logout, page reloads, localStorage keeps the same info it got on login and entire Vuex Panel on VueDev tools resets.

This is my code.

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState()
  ],
  state: {
    token: null,
    user: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setToken (state, token) {
      console.log('mutation1')
      state.token = token
    },
    setUser (state, userData) {
      console.log('mutation2')
      state.user = userData.username
      state.cargo = userData.cargo
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setToken ({commit}, token) {
      console.log('action1')
      commit('setToken', token)
    },
    setUser ({commit}, userData) {
      console.log('action1')
      commit('setUser', userData)
    }
  }
})
```

**Login method on login component**

```
async login () {
  try {
    const response = await AuthenticationService.ingresar({
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    })
    const { username, cargo, token } = response.data
    this.$store.dispatch('setToken', token)
    this.$store.dispatch('setUser', { username, cargo })
  } catch (error) {
    this.error = error.response.data.error
  }
}
```

**LogOut method on navbar component**

```
logout () {
  this.$store.dispatch('setToken', null)
  this.$store.dispatch('setUser', null)
  this.$router.push('/')
}
```

Everything works if I disable vuex-persistedstate.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my bad. Got an **href=" "** on link calling the logout function. This was reloading the page and not calling the function. Therefore doing nothing with the state. Took me centuries to find it. Nevermind. :)